# GetModuleHandle return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Tags: c++, windows, dll, module, dll-injection

So I am learning some dll injection stuff on a test executable. Once I have injected my dll, I try to get the module handle and with that I try to get the base address of the module(the main exe).

```
DWORD dwGetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD dwProcessIdentifier, WCHAR *lpszModuleName) 
{ 
   HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwProcessIdentifier); 
   DWORD dwModuleBaseAddress = 0; 
   if(hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
   { 
      MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry32 = {0}; 
      ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32); 
      if(Module32First(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32)) 
      { 
         do 
         { 
            if(wcscmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, lpszModuleName) == 0) 
            { 
               dwModuleBaseAddress = (DWORD)ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr; 
               break; 
            } 
         } 
         while(Module32Next(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32)); 
      } 
      CloseHandle(hSnapshot); 
   } 
   return dwModuleBaseAddress; 
}
```

That is how I try to do it. This is after my dll is injected, but it seems to return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE for some reason. I found the function from one website and modified it a bit but it still doesn't seem to work. If you have a more cleaner method to get the base address I would be glad to know about it.

Edit the problem is now with this line:

```
if(wcscmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, lpszModuleName) == 0)
```

It never is 0 but there is a module name I am looking for, I can see my exe in the debugger but this comparison doesn't somehow work.

This is how I call the function

```
HWND window = FindWindow(0, LPCWSTR("test"));
DWORD pID = 0; 
GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, &pID); 
base = dwGetModuleBaseAddress(pID, (WCHAR*)("test"));
```

Comment: you can use getlasterror() to see what's happening

Comment: Are you saying CreateToolhelp32Snapshot returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE? Check GetLastError() for the error code. That might give you a better idea of what might have happened.

Comment: Okay, now the problem is with this line: if(wcscmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, lpszModuleName) == 0)

Comment: That (WCHAR*) cast only stopped the compiler from telling you are doing it wrong, it didn't stop you from doing it wrong.  Use L"test" to create a Unicode string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You are using functions designed for wide character strings.

```
"test"
L"test"
```

The top line is a regular c string char array.  The second line is using the L macro to define the string literal as a wide char c string.

Casting to WCHAR* will not solve the issue, you either have to define them using the L macro or switch your functions to use regular char arrays.

Here is a regular char array version of your function I use

```cpp
char* GetModuleBaseAddress(const char* modName, DWORD procId)
{
    char* modBaseAddr{ nullptr };
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry{};
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_stricmp(modEntry.szModule, modName))
                {
                    modBaseAddr = (char*)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return modBaseAddr;
}
```